# How can i make a link to update my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, url, hyperlink, app-store

i know how to make a link to my app on the appstore with this URL itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id= 
but i don't want the user goes on the software page but directly in the update tab 
what is the link to do this?
is there a link to update the app ?(if an update existing)
thanks

Answer (score 6):

Launching App Store is explained in "QA1629: Launching the App Store from an iPhone application":

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1629.html

I'm not sure if it's possible to link directly to an update. I've found once
an advice to replace "viewSoftware" to "viewSoftwareUpdate" on:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/139548#139548

but since link for "phobos" is no longer used it might not work any more.