# Can my app provide an "Update in App Store" link?

Tags: iphone, upgrade, app-store

For various reasons I need my iPhone app to include a way to tell the user that a new update for the app is available and prompt them to go update in the App Store.

It looks like there used to be an undocumented way to give an HTML link that would lead the iPhone to open the Upgrade page for app, or something?

[How can i make a link to update my iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628665/how-can-i-make-a-link-to-update-my-iphone-application)

https://devforums.apple.com/message/139548#139548

Unfortunately it appears that iTunes links have changed format from these old "Phobos"-type links (which used "WebObjects") to something new? I'm not very familiar with the old system or the new one...

Can I create a link that will take my users directly to the "upgrade apps" screen on the App Store? Or even better, one that will initiate the upgrade for my app immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides an iTunes Link Maker tool which you can use: http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker

Just put the "Media Type" as apps and type in the app name.  [Apple recommends](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1629.html#TNTAG2) using an `NSURLConnection` for opening the link within your app since it will cut out all of the re-directing that goes on and open straight into the AppStore app.

Comment: I don't see how this specifically takes an iPhone user to the "Upgrade page" for my app? Won't it just take them to the general page for the app?

Comment: Are you sure phobos links don't work anymore??  This still uses one http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1629.html

Comment: He's not looking for opening HIS app in the app store, he wants to take the user to the screen where they Update their apps to the latest version so that he can encourage his users to stay up to date.

Comment: @KennyWyland Might want to read the question again: `Or even better, one that will initiate the upgrade for my app immediately?`